# Weird TextBoxFor mapping issue on Edit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, model

When I'm editting an `Animal` item, I'm seeing that the field for "ID" is populated with the value of the field "idAnimal".  The animal model is retrieved from database (using EF) by the id passed as parameter. The parameter named "id" is the key named "idAnimal" in database.

Debugging in the controller, the model has its values OK (ID = null, idAnimal = some int)... and debugging at the Razor view, I can see that using `@Model.ID` is null also...  but once the view is rendered I see a value in the textbox.

My model is as follows:

```
public class Animal
{
   public int idAnimal {get; set;}  //this is the id in database
   public int ID {get; set;}       //this is the id given at birth to the animal, a business concept 

   //The rest of the properties
}
```

In my controller's EDIT action, I have:

```
public virtual ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
     Animal myA = db.Animals.Find(id);
     return PartialView(myA)
}
```

In the view I have:

```
@model MyApp.Model.Animal
    ....

    @Html.LabelForX(model => model.ID)
    <div class="input">
       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ID, new { @class = "medium", size = 30 })
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID)
    </div>

     ....
```

The only thing that could be happening, being weird, is that the parameter named "id" (which holds the value in the field "idAnimal") could be interfering some how.

Hope this all soup of id's is understandable :)

Comment: Does the problem go away if you change the name of ID to something else, like tag? I wonder if there's some weird keyword mapping in razor that puts ID to the identity field.

Comment: Well, I just changed teh parameter name in the action method and it worked... so indeed is some mapping issue. It is a known issue?

Comment: Well, it is now! :) I don't know if there's a way to file a bug report on that sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the ID property to something else, such as Tag. I suspect there is a bug where model.ID pulls the primary key from the model, not the column ID.

Comment: Well, I finally changed the model, to avoid this happening in other places of the app.